# Unable to display toast messages

Tags: codenameone

I have download and use the code form the following URL

**https://github.com/Pmovil/Toast**  to display toast message.

Initially I got NativeToastImpl Not implemented error. I have resolved by coping the native related code to my project. Now the System throws Runtime Exception "Toast is not supported in this platform."

Here is my code to display toast message.

```
public class MyApplication {

private Form current;

private static Object context;

public void init(Object context) {
    MyApplication.context = context;
}

public static Object getContext() {
    return context;
}

public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }

    showLoginForm();
}

public void stop() {
    current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
}

public void destroy() {
}

private void showLoginForm() {

    Form form = new Form("WelCome ...");

    Button b = new Button(" Login ");

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            Log.p(" Came hgere ");
            Log.p(" ***    " + MyApplication.getContext());
            Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getContext(), "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    });
    form.addComponent(b);
    form.show();
}}
```

I have used Net Beans IDE for development, OS : windows 8.1

Please let me know I am doing wrong in this code and

Is there any other way to display toast messages using codename one?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to place the cn1lib in the libs directory and refresh, not copy native files: https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_libraries_cn1lib

Comment: As far as I recall this library isn't supported on all platforms and you need to test if toast works for the given platform. You can also check out the new Codename One `ToastBar` : https://www.codenameone.com/blog/toastbar-gaussian-blur.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please edit the following code and please test the toast in device . Toast is not available in emulator.

```
public void init(Object context) {
   this.context = context;
}

b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Log.p(" Came hgere ");

        Toast.makeText(context, "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have changed the code to  Toast.makeText(context, "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `show()`     method on Toast.

```
Toast.makeText(MyApplication.getContext(), "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```